# Foreach is showing "Array" instead of selected items from dynamically generated checkboxes

Tags: php

I'm trying to capture a user's checkbox selection from a dynamically generated list of options but I'm getting "Array" instead of the names selected.

In my last test, I checked 2 of the three boxes and got 3 instances of "Array" back.

This is my query that finds the names:

```
$query = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name 
          FROM users WHERE location_id = " . $location_id;
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) 
{
    die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $name = $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="emp_name[]" id="emp_name[]" value="' . $name . '"> ' . $name . '</label>';
}
```

I then post the array of names like this:

```
$attendee = $_POST['emp_name'];
```

And try to generate the list of names for my email like this:

```
$values = ('emp_name');
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $$value = (array)$_POST[$value];
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < count($attendee); $i++){
        $attendees = array();
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $attendees[] = ${$value}[$i];
        }
```

Can someone help me see what's wrong?

---

I changed my code and included a part of the html that I'm trying to render:

```
foreach ($attendee as $name) {
            $attendees[] = $name;

            $htmlBody .= "<tr><td>{$attendees}</td></tr>";
        }
```

But it still returns Array.

Comment: try a `var_dump()` on the `$_POST` variable to see how it's nested

Comment: I just noticed I'm getting an array to string conversion notice in my error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you do this:

```
$attendee = (array)$_POST['emp_name'];
```

Try to replace it with:

```
$attendee = $_POST['emp_name'];
```

From your question it's not too clear, but I think you're creating an array within an array,and that that's the issue.

If the above doesn't help, try to var_dump() the variable that gives you "Array" response, and you'll see what's within it.

EDIT: In addition to the change above, try to make this change too:

Replace all this code:

```
$values = ('emp_name');
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $$value = (array)$_POST[$value];
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($attendee); $i++){
    $attendees = array();
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $attendees[] = ${$value}[$i];
    }
```

with:

```
foreach ($_POST['emp_name'] as $name) {
    $attendees[] = $name;
}
```

EDIT #2:

According to your code:

```
foreach ($attendee as $name) {
            $attendees[] = $name;

            $htmlBody .= "<tr><td>{$attendees}</td></tr>";
        }
```

It's totally normal that you're getting Array instead of a name. See, by writing:

```
   $attendees[] = $name;
```

you're implying to php that it's an array. On the other hand the foreach loop does the opposite thing, it takes each of the values from $attendee array and makes it available to you as $name variable. So you're basically doing the right thing, and then reverting it back to array for no reason.

SOLUTION:

Replace `{$attendees}` with `{$name}`. And it should work.

Comment: Your replacement is the same as what I wrote.

Comment: Didn't work. I think my foreach needs to be changed.

Comment: What do you get when you do this:  var_dump($attendee);

Comment: I get this: `array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "name 1" [1]=> string(10) "name 2" }`

Comment: I changed the names because they were actual people's names, lol.

Comment: Cool. Now, I edited my answer, see if it helps. But in addition to that - from this var_dump, it's clear that your $attendee variable is an array. You can access it's elements like this:  echo $attendee[1]; will show name 2.  $attendee[1] = 'Joe' will change name 2 to Joe. Or you can access all the elements using the loop: foreach ($attendee as $name) {echo "$name<br>";}    Hope this helps.

Comment: Still getting back Array. Only once this time. I don't know if I can do $attendee[1] like you mentioned in your comment because the number of people will change depending on other factors.

Comment: You are correct, using loop is safest. Btw. If you're still getting an Array, that simply means you have another Array wrapped within previous one. Is the loop from my previous comment giving you names or Array?

Comment: Array. Did you see the update to my question? That is the intended usage: a new table row for each name. Although, I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Just saw the update, and updated my answer too, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can write that with alot less code.
`$attendees` will now contain your checked checkboxes.

```
$attendees = array()
foreach($_POST['emp_name'] as $name){
     $attendees[] = $name;
}
```

Comment: @Mike Why would you try that?

Comment: Because it's 2:48 AM and I'll try anything at this point ... Can't think anymore. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Mike Oh sorry didn't think you were the OP. Answered more questions the last half hour.:)